# How can avoid URL filtering?

Tags: proxy, blocking

In my country access to URLs with keyword 'sex' is denied.
Is it possible to encode URL?
For example: When i want to download a file from Rapishare (URL contains sex)
I can't use proxy such as Ultrasurf.
I must encode URL. Is there any solution?

thanx

Comment: FREE THE PR0N :P